Exchange of groups of bits in places in long double. C++
I am faced with the problem of swapping groups of bits in places in a long double
Here's a snippet of code that doesn't work rocket-wise:
void swapBytes(long double& value, int byte1, int byte2, int byteCount) 
{
    unsigned char* bytes = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&value);
    for (int i = 0; i < byteCount; ++i) {
        std::swap(bytes[byte1 - i], bytes[byte2 - i]);
    }
}


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Непонятно, что вы вообще хотите, потому что в общем случае это работать не будет. Для каких конкретно входных данных вы его вызываете? Какую задачу вы решаете?

опять же если предполагать, что в операция имеет смысл, надо помнить про https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

ручная модификация данных с использованием reinterpret_cast будет работать только используя типы, в которым подразумевается неожиданное поведение (volatile). void swapBytes ( long double volatile & , unsigned char volatile * bytes =      reinterpret_cast < unsigned char volatile *>(
